# XAMPP not automatic add MySQL to service?

Tags: mysql, service, xampp

I see that XAMPP not add automatic add mysql service to service of windows.

I try to add manualy by use command: mysqld --install. Ok add mysql to service but I can't start this service.

And when mysql is add to service, XAMPP control can't start mysql until I delete mysql service.
Can I add mysql to service? Because I want mysql auto start. I know I can config XAMPP control to startup with windows, but I want to try using service.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: xampp comes with mariaDB and not ySQL

Comment: Use the control panel to add the DBMS as a service. Then it will be done as XAMPP expects